# Does Entity Framework return the Entire Dataset?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Using:

- .Net 4.0
- EntityFramework 4.3

IF I query a DBSet in this manner:

```
public DbSet<Reciept> Reciepts { get; set; }
Reciepts.Where(rec =>rec.Number == reciept.Number &&
                        rec.Project.ID == reciept.Project.ID);
```

Will the entire table be returned, and THEN filterd by my query?

Or does it somehow translate this into SQL (Linq2SQL?), and return ONLY those rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only return filtered values.

You can always check the generated query by pointing a mouse cursor at a query variable while in debug:

```
var query = Reciepts.Where(rec =>rec.Number == reciept.Number && rec.Project.ID == reciept.Project.ID);
// put breakpoint here and stop mouse cursor at a 'query' variable
```

Another great tool which can be used to check what is really being sent to the DB is SQL Server Profiler (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx). I use it all the time while developing with EF.